# How to swap elements in a System.Numerics.Vector

Tags: c#, sorting, simd, median, system.numerics.vectors

My task is to speed up a median filter by using SIMD. I have found a tutorial to sort the elements of a vector. However, in this one, elements of the vector are swapped in pairs. Yet, I have not found a command for this for the System.Numerics.Vector class.
Is there an efficient way to sort the elements of such a vector or another efficient C# implementation of a median filter using SIMD?
Thank You in advance!

I found a promising video under
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qejTqnxQRcw

So I started to become aquainted with the basic concepts of System.Numerics.Vector like copying data and basic operations like min and max. For the approach in the video a swapping operation is, however, required, as well, which I could not find int the documentation of System.Numerics.Vector class.

Comment: See github : http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/group__median__filter.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1):

System.Numerics.Vector is too high level.
Low-level SIMD instructions in .NET operate on fixed-size types, `Vector128` and `Vector256`

Here’s an example for PC platform which sorts FP32 elements stored in a 16-bytes vector. The algorithm is called “sorting network”, Wikipedia [has a nice illustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#/media/File:SimpleSortingNetworkFullOperation.svg).

```
static Vector128<float> sortLanes( Vector128<float> x )
{
    // Flip high + low halves, with _MM_SHUFFLE( 1, 0, 3, 2 )
    var tmp = Sse.Shuffle( x, x, 0x4E );
    // Sort and blend
    var i = Sse.Min( x, tmp );
    var ax = Sse.Max( x, tmp );
    x = Sse41.Blend( i, ax, 0b1100 );

    // Flip even / odd lanes, with _MM_SHUFFLE( 2, 3, 0, 1 )
    tmp = Sse.Shuffle( x, x, 0xB1 );
    // Sort and blend
    i = Sse.Min( x, tmp );
    ax = Sse.Max( x, tmp );
    x = Sse41.Blend( i, ax, 0b1010 );

    // Sorting two lanes in the middle, _MM_SHUFFLE( 3, 1, 2, 0 )
    tmp = Sse.Shuffle( x, x, 0xD8 );
    // Sort and blend
    i = Sse.Min( x, tmp );
    ax = Sse.Max( x, tmp );
    return Sse41.Blend( i, ax, 0b1100 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this information! However, I was unfortunately unsuccessful in finding understandable documentation about "Sse.Shuffle" and therefore do not understand the answer. Where can I find information about SSE commands please?

Comment: @Jürgen Microsoft’s .NET API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.sse.shuffle?view=net-7.0
It doesn’t explain anything, but it refers to `_mm_shuffle_ps` intrinsic, documented by Intel there: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm_shuffle_ps&ig_expand=6430

Comment: @Jürgen See also illustration on page 14 of that PDF http://const.me/articles/simd/simd.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET 7.0, the `Vector128.Shuffle` and `Vector128.Shuffle` methods have been provided, which can be used to swap elements.
But Vector still doesn't provide a Shuffle method.

I wrote the VectorTraits library. This library provides the [Vectors.Shuffle](https://zyl910.github.io/VectorTraits_doc/api/Zyl.VectorTraits.Vectors.Shuffle.html#Zyl_VectorTraits_Vectors_Shuffle_System_Numerics_Vector_System_Byte__System_Numerics_Vector_System_Byte__) method. It supports swapping elements for Vector.
It supports hardware acceleration on X86 and Arm platforms, and it supports lower versions of `.NET` programs (`.NET Core 3.0`+, `.NET 5.0`+ ...).

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/VectorTraits